# синхронизация выполнения инструкций PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, имеется ли синхронизация выполнения инструкций PHP с работой компьютера в реальном времени? Иными словами, есть ли гарантия, что после выполнения `unlink(name)` инструкция `file_exists(name)` даст `FALSE`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

К PHP Ваш вопрос отношения не имеет. А имеет он к апи операционной системы. Поэтмоу будем ближе к железу. Если подряд идут две строки `unlink(name)` и `file_exists(name)` в пределах одного потока и файл удалился удачно, то да, `file_exists` возвратит `FALSE`. Если же функции вызваются в разных тредах (разных скриптах) и Вам кажеться (по логам например), что порядок соблюден, то результат `file_exists(name)` может быть любой - файловой системе нужно некоторое время на обновление данных и это время вполне может быть  несколько секунд на загруженных системах. И это нормально.